# How to define m*n output?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am writing Verilog code for a shift-left register which stores its value after each shift in sub registers. Can I define the output registers as an array like this?  The provided code is just a simple example to show the concept, not my code:

```
module test(a,b,c);
  input a,b;
  output [7:0] c [3:0];
endmodule
```

instead of

```
module test(a,b,c1,c2,c3,c4);
  input a,b;
  output [7:0] c1,c2,c3,c4;
endmodule
```

and for the first way, how I can call `c[i]`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can very much use a 2D array at the output, like in your first example. Check out Section 5 of this paper by Stuart Sutherland; this should give you some confidence. The section is titled `Module Ports`.

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sutherland-hdl.com%2Fpapers%2F2006-SNUG-Europe_SystemVerilog_synthesis_paper.pdf&ei=7KmYUNKPN6GyigKDnoHwDA&usg=AFQjCNGmr3flHrARC-w40xveo8zitcdjfg&cad=rja

Also, elaborating on your first example, you can define your module this way for clarity:

```
module lshift(clk, reset, a, c);
input wire clk, reset;
input wire [7:0] a;
output reg [7:0] c [0:3]; // <-- defining the unpacked dimension as [0:3] for clarity

always@(posedge clk) begin
   if(reset) begin
       c[0] <= 8'd0;
       ...
       c[3] <= 8'd0;
   end
   else begin
       c[0] <= a;
       c[1] <= c[0];
       c[2] <= c[1];
       c[3] <= c[2];
   end
end
endmodule
```

... and now you can slice into your array. `c[0], c[1] .. c[3]` each represents a byte, and `c[0][3:0]` would mean the lower nibble of the first byte.

Comment: thanks, i tryit but it give me  'c' has not been declared; i don't know why?

Comment: your simulator just may not support multidimensional ports

Comment: @user1643699 - I tried this piece of code with **Synopsys VCS** and it works fine .. Synthesize-able and Simulate-able.